# Why does "fly-animation" doesn't apply to first 2 blocks

Tags: jquery, animation

I've created a little script for sliding some elements (like "fly-in" effect) from the right and left sides while scrolling http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPPKxX. Also I wanted to apply this effect for elements directly after page is loaded (before any scrolling). But as a result first 2 elements, which I can see, appear at center of the page, but not from the right or left side. Can anyone explain me what the problem is? Thanks in advance!
This is a part of JS code:

```
 var FlyInBlocks = {
  anim: function(_element) {
    var elDirect = $(_element).data("direction"),
      winScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
      winHeight = $(window).height(),
      winWidth = $(window).width(),
      elPos = $(_element).offset().top,
      resHeight = elPos - winHeight;
    $(_element).css(elDirect, -winWidth + "px");

    if (winScrollTop >= resHeight) {
      $(_element).addClass("b-fly-visible").css(elDirect, "0");
    }
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".block").each(function() {
    FlyInBlocks.anim(this);
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".block").each(function() {
      FlyInBlocks.anim(this);
    });
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

From your codepen link it doesn't show the animation on load, nor on scroll. If you add margin top to the top area, it does start to show on scroll. My guess is that you should change this part:

```
if (winScrollTop >= resHeight) {
  $(_element).addClass("b-fly-visible").css(elDirect, "0");
}
```

Always run it on the first iteration and only after that check for (winScrollTop >= resHeight) , because it will never add the class 'b-fly-visible' if the element starts at the top.